# UseMemo does not return any values

Tags: reactjs

I have the following scenario. I pass an object array (houses) to a component. Then I want to loop through this within a useMemo function and display it in the return method. However, I can't see anything. UseMemo is called and run through, but as I said, I don't see any objects

```
export default function CompactView({ houses }) {

const houseMemo = useMemo(() => {
houses?.map((house) => {
  return (
       <div>
        ...
       </div>              
     );
   });
}, [houses]);

return (
<>
 ...
  <div>
    {houseMemo}
  </div>
</>

 );
}
```

Comment: Either explicitly specify `return` in your `useMemo` callback (`return houses?.map(...)`), or omit the curly braces (`useMemo(() => houses?.map(...), [houses])`)

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are having is the arrow function in your useMemo. It is missing the returns statement. Your code should look something like this:

```
const houseMemo = useMemo(() => {
return houses?.map((house) => {
  return (
       <div>
        ...
       </div>              
     );
   });
}, [houses]);
```

Notice the return before `houses?.map` or you can change it to:

```
  const houseMemo = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      houses?.map((house) => {
        return <div>...</div>;
      }),
    [houses]
  );
```

In second code sample, I've remoed the {} brackets inside useMemo callback. Hope it helps